# How to get count of Facebook notification using selenium in python?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I used java code to get logged in and fetch count of messages as well as notification using `gettext()` function, And tried one code in Python to fetch the same values but unable to get results. My Python code is as - 
`noti = driver.find_elements_by_id("notificationsCountValue")`

Comment: try `.text()` instead of `gettext()`

Comment: Don't scrape Facebook because it is not allowed by Facebook Terms of Service. Use the API.

Comment: I tried it but getting error message on execution - `noti = driver.find_elements_by_id("notificationsCountValue").text()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: @Wizkid - Ohhhh... I was just doing for my test case study.

Comment: @wizkid - Learning API... Can you suggest how the problem is solved using Facebook API?

Comment: There is no way to do it using the API.

Comment: it is `element` not `elements` , so therefore it will look like `driver.find_element_by_id("notificationsCountValue").text()`